# Can I put shopping cart there?

Tags: placement, shopping-cart

As far as I know, right top corner (near or on the nav bar) is where users typically look for a shopping cart. But here I have my navigation in a sidebar, so is it justified to put the shopping cart where I did? I feel like it would take a lot of space elsewhere.

Or should I maybe squeeze it somewhere in the top bar, where The  User and App Name is?

This is a desktop application, just so you know. And it's not going to be a complicated project, so I feel like shopping cart in the sidebar is not such a bad idea.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks a bit scattered. There is a possibility that users might get used to it. But, try to think about functionality, the menu function is to navigate the application and your cart is giving information and is *probably clickable(?)*.

#### Here is an example of what would I do:

[image]

#### Description by sections:

- Title bar contains name of the app and actions
- Search + Username + Cart

  - Search should be big if your customers know what are they buying
  - Username dropdown should contain 'My account' and 'Settings' **if** those settings are referring to 'My account'. **If not** 'Settings' icon should be next to the 'Cart'.
  - Hovering the cart shows item prices. *If* you really need to show them all the time [image]
  - Now you have your information segmented in a functional way.
- Where am I? Shop
- Filters: if there can be multiple it's nice to have them above what needs to be filtered out

  - **if** there is only one filter, I would mind putting it next to the 'Store' label
- In the end, the most important, items.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

the answer to this question is user test it with a version where the elements are across the top. You want to test how familiar each user is with each layout and how fast they can complete tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Blunt answers is yes. You can put the cart wherever you want to but the real question here is whether the user will know intuitively where it is.

As colmcq says in their answer, user testing different versions will give you the answer you're after. I have done something similar in the past with a tablet app, the only room we had (inherited project) was to put the cart on the left. Initial user testing proved that peoples eyes and attention when looking for the cart (almost all of the time) went to the top right as this is the standard now.

Like everything in UX - **if in doubt, test it**

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: Yes, but top right is better**

Pick 20 eCommerce stores starting with the most popular and look at the placement of the shopping cart.

[Most popular US ecommerce sites](https://trellis.co/blog/top-ten-us-ecommerce-retail-sites-by-revenue/)

Your users are likely to use these and similar sites.

These sites all have the shopping cart in that position, so that's where your users expect to see it.

Even a slight stumbling block like this, can make your users less likely to complete a purchase.

The shopping cart is a key part of your users journey and needs to be as simple as possible.

This article for example shows that moving the logo into the center (rather than the top left as expected) makes navigation to the homepage up to 6 times harder.

[Logo placement article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/centered-logos/)

You don't want to make your shopping cart hard to find; stick to the top right.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, yes, you could have the shopping cart section anywhere on the page. 
However, keep in mind that the western reading direction plays a huge role in how we interpret movement and perceived changes in the status of things.

Your users are more likely to read in that direction, and when purchasing things online, they tend to scan the shopping cart regularly. The mental model of objects going to the cart is better interpreted from left to right I believe. Also, if they are purchasing more than one product and want to keep adding products, checking on the shopping cart details and total might be another task they are repeating, and the cursor is way more likely to be resting at the right side of the screen as well. 
I'd personally put it on the right side, hope this helps!